# Fazer update usando registro diferentes da mesma tabela

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-update, campos

Preciso fazer um *update* que atualize o registro do campo de uma tabela, usando outro registro da mesma tabela e mesmo campo.
Minha tabela é a seguinte:

```
select produto,valor_bruto,acrescimo,valor_liquido 
  from tab_itens 
 where data='2021-06-10' 
   and caixa=8 
   and cupom in (145,146)
```

No cupom 145, os valores dos campos "valor_bruto", "acrescimo" e "valor_liquido" estão corretos, entretanto, no cupom 146 que é uma venda duplicada, os valores dos campos "acrescimo" e "valor_liquido" ficaram errados.

Eu tentei a seguinte *query*:

```
update tab_itens set 
   acrescimo=(select acrescimo 
                from tab_itens 
               where cast(data as date)='2021-06-10' 
                 and caixa=8 
                 and cupom=145)
where cast(data as date)='2021-06-10' 
  and caixa=8 
  and cupom=146;
```

O resultado do sql server foi:

> Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 10 A subconsulta retornou mais
> de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=,
> <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão.

Como eu faço para atualizar os campos "acrescimo" e "valor_bruto" do cupom 146, usando os mesmos campos só que do cupom 145?

Estrutura da tabela
[image: Estrutura da tabela]

Comment: Qual a estrutura da tabela `tab_itens`?

Comment: Clarck, a estrutura inteira?

Comment: Pode ser apenas com os principais campos, principalmente com os campos chaves da tabela e os campos envolvidos na operação de atualização.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que no seu comando de `update` a subconsulta está retornando mais de 1 registro como informado na mensagem de erro.

Para corrigir, precisará relacionar a subconsulta de tal forma que retornará apenas 1 registro.
Para essa finalidade de retornar apenas um valor por registro, acrescente os campos `item` e `cod_produto` na subconsulta:

```
update tab_itens set 
   acrescimo=(select acrescimo 
                from tab_itens cp145
               where cast(data as date)='2021-06-10' 
                 and caixa=8 
                 and cupom=145
                 and cp145.item = tab_itens.item 
                 and cp145.cod_produto = tab_itens.cod_produto)
where cast(data as date)='2021-06-10' 
  and caixa=8 
  and cupom=146;
```

Foi atribuído alias `cp145` para referenciar a `tab_itens` na subconsulta:

```
from tab_itens cp145
```

> no cupom 146 que é uma venda duplicada, os valores dos campos
> "acrescimo" e "valor_liquido" ficaram errados.

Considerando que os cupons são uma venda duplicada, os campos **Item** e **Cod_Produto** devem ser iguais em ambos os registros, devendo serem utilizados para realizar a restrição de busca na subconsulta, o que resultará em apenas 1 valor para cada item, permitindo assim a atualização. Por isso, acrescentei o complemento seguinte ao seu `update`:

```
and cp145.item = tab_itens.item 
and cp145.cod_produto = tab_itens.cod_produto
```

Siga o exemplo para atualizar o valor do campo "valor_liquido".

Realizei um teste que está disponível em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/da66d8/1.

Comment: Desculpe a demora em responder, mas me ajudou bastante. Obrigado pelo apoio Clarck.

Comment: Ótimo @RodyM.Good, que bom que ajudei. Por favor, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)